# how to show a specific value for a non existing value in second table in join?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, `City(city_id, city_name)` and `count_staff_in_city(city_id, count_staff)`. the first table keeps the name of the **city** and its **id**, and the second table keeps **the number of staffs working in each city**. I want to join this 2 table in this way: if `City.city_id` exists in `count_staff_in_city.city_id` then show its value in select. if `City.city_id` does not exists in `count_staff_in_city`, then **0** should appear in output for this city.

how can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an outer join and replce NULLs using COALESCE:

```
SELECT C.city_name, COALESCE(CS.count_staff,0) AS count_staff
FROM City AS C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN count_staff_in_city AS CS ON C.city_id = CS.city_id;
```